# How to read merged cell from word document

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I am getting the below exception while reading the merged cell.

"Cannot access individual rows in this collection because the table has vertically merged cells."

My code is,

```
foreach (Row aRow in doc.Tables[i].Rows)
{
   foreach (Cell aCell in aRow.Cells)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(aCell.Range.Text);
   }
}
```

// My table format is..

| R1C1 |R1C2|**______**|

| R2C1 |R2C2|  R*C3   ..|

| R3C1 |R3C2|**______**|

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
Table table = Globals.ThisDocument.Tables[1];
Range range = table.Range;
for (int i = 1; i <= range.Cells.Count; i++)
{
    if(range.Cells[i].RowIndex == table.Rows.Count)
    {
        range.Cells[i].Range.Text = range.Cells[i].RowIndex + ":" + range.Cells[i].ColumnIndex;
        MessageBox.Show(range.Cells[i].Range.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it really helps me. any one want to use this code just remove the below line "range.Cells[i].Range.Text = range.Cells[i].RowIndex + ":" + range.Cells[i].ColumnIndex;" in above code...

Comment: one more query regarding merged cell...:)
How to find the count/number of paragraphs in the table (having merged cell)? 
How can I get the current paragraph number in the word document.

Answer (score 0):

Table.Range.Cells can be enumerated:

```
foreach (Cell cell in doc.Tables[i].Range.Cells)
{
    Debug.Print(cell.Range.Text);
}
```